# How to return a view from parent controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I know how to do redirect from parent controller, suppose I have

```
public class _ParentController : Controller {  
    ...
}

public class HomeController : _ParentController {  
    ...
}
```

I can add a method to `_ParentController`:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (condition) {
        filterContext.Result = Redirect(path);
    }
}
```

Now I need to return a view or do Server.Transfer (I need to preserve the url). `Server.TransferRequest` doesn't work for me in this case, is there any other way to do what I need? I use .NET MVC3 and IIS7.5

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `filterContext.Result = View(somePameter);` ?

Comment: "I know `hot to do` redirect from parent controller, suppose I have " is it `how to do` ?

Comment: @tschmit007 awesome, thanks, it's what I need, simple but I didn't figure out it myself. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
filterContext.Result = View(someParameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

For example you can have:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnException(filterContext);
    if (((filterContext.Exception is SecurityException)) ||
        ((filterContext.Exception is AuthenticationException)))
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        filterContext.Result = View("Error", "You don't have permission");
    }
}
```

This will set the result of action to view of your choice, preserving current url. *(keep in mind that view have to be found in folder according to current route or in shared folder)*

```
filterContext.Result = View("Name of view", "object model")';
```